# Recreate structure of html page from array

Tags: php, html, arrays, foreach, tags

Good morning everyone,
I'm trying to recreate a html page extracting data from an array.
This is the array

```
    $MiniSiteStructureArray = array(
    'section_1' => array(
        'class' => 'main full',
        'contents' => array(
            'img' => array(
                'class' => 'logo',
                'src' => 'assets/images/logo-480x176.png'
            ),
            'div' => array(
                'class' => 'cover sfondo',
                'img' => array(
                    'class' => 'cover-image',
                    'src' => 'assets/images/cover-img-header.png'
                )
            ),
            'div_1' => array(
                'class' => 'cover-mob sfondo-mob',
                'img' => array(
                    'class' => 'cover-image-mob',
                    'src' => 'assets/images/cover-img-mobile.jpg'
                )
            ),
            'a' => array(
                'class' => 'button order light',
                'div' => array(
                    'class' => 'data-min',
                    'div' => array(
                        'class' => 'label-holder',
                        'img' => array(
                            'src' => 'assets/images/sfondo-cta.jpg'
                        ),
                        'p' => array(
                            'class' => 'label',
                            'strong' => 'text'
                        )
                    ),
                    'div_1' => array(
                        'class' => 'price-holder'
                    )
                )
            ),
            'div_2' => array(
                'class' => 'cta',
                'p' => array(
                    'class' => 'main-title',
                    'a' => array(
                        'strong' => 'text'
                    )
                )
            ),
            'img_1' => array(
                'class' => 'main-title',
                'src' => 'assets/images/extra_1.png'
            )
        )
    ),
    'section_2' => array(
        'class' => 'gallery',
        'id' => 'video',
        'contents' => array(
            'p' => array(
                'class' => 'title video-title',
                'span' => array(
                    'strong' => 'text'
                )
            ),
            'div' => array(
                'class' => 'container',
                'div' => array(
                    'class' => 'arrow-container prev',
                    'img' => array(
                        'class' => 'arrow',
                        'src' => 'assets/images/freccia-sx_1.png'
                    )
                ),
                'div_1' => array(
                    'class' => 'arrow-container next',
                    'img' => array(
                        'class' => 'arrow',
                        'src' => 'assets/images/freccia-dx_1.png'
                    )
                ),
                'div_2' => array(
                    'class' => 'gallery-holder',
                    'div' => array(
                        'class' => 'internal single',
                        'div' => array(
                            'class' => 'gallery-item video',
                            'div' => array(
                                'class' => 'wrapper video-wrapper',
                                'img' => array(
                                    'class' => 'play-vid pointer thumb',
                                    'src' => 'assets/images/img-spot-tv.png'
                                ),
                                'img_1' => array(
                                    'class' => 'play-icon hover',
                                    'src' => 'assets/images/play.png'
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    'section_3' => array(
        'class' => 'gallery',
        'id' => 'image',
        'contents' => array(
            'p' => array(
                'class' => 'title image-title',
                'span' => array(
                    'strong' => array(
                        'strong' => 'text'
                    )
                )
            ),
            'div' => array(
                'class' => 'container',
                'div' => array(
                    'class' => 'arrow-container prev',
                    'img' => array(
                        'class' => 'arrow',
                        'src' => 'assets/images/freccia-sx_1.png'
                    )
                ),
                'div_1' => array(
                    'class' => 'arrow-container next',
                    'img' => array(
                        'class' => 'arrow',
                        'src' => 'assets/images/freccia-dx_1.png'
                    )
                ),
                'div_2' => array(
                    'class' => 'gallery-holder',
                    'div' => array(
                        'class' => 'internal single',
                        'div' => array(
                            'class' => 'gallery-item',
                            'div' => array(
                                'class' => 'wrapper image-wrapper',
                                'img' => array(
                                    'class' => 'thumb',
                                    'src' => 'assets/images/img-1.png'
                                ),
                                'p' => array(
                                    'class' => 'caption image-caption',
                                    'span' => 'text'
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                    'div_1' => array(
                        'class' => 'internal single',
                        'div' => array(
                            'class' => 'gallery-item',
                            'div' => array(
                                'class' => 'wrapper image-wrapper',
                                'img' => array(
                                    'class' => 'thumb',
                                    'src' => 'assets/images/img-2.png'
                                ),
                                'p' => array(
                                    'class' => 'caption image-caption',
                                    'span' => 'text'
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                    'div_2' => array(
                        'class' => 'internal single',
                        'div' => array(
                            'class' => 'gallery-item',
                            'div' => array(
                                'class' => 'wrapper image-wrapper',
                                'img' => array(
                                    'class' => 'thumb',
                                    'src' => 'assets/images/img-3.png'
                                ),
                                'p' => array(
                                    'class' => 'caption image-caption',
                                    'span' => 'text'
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                    'div_i' => array(
                        'class' => 'internal single',
                        'div' => array(
                            'class' => 'gallery-item',
                            'div' => array(
                                'class' => 'wrapper image-wrapper',
                                'img' => array(
                                    'class' => 'thumb',
                                    'src' => 'assets/images/img-i.png'
                                ),
                                'p' => array(
                                    'class' => 'caption image-caption',
                                    'span' => 'text'
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                )
            ),
            'div_1' => array(
                'class' => 'counter'
            )
        )
    ),
    'section_4' => array(
        'class' => 'main',
        'id' => 'info',
        'contents' => array(
            'div' => array(
                'class' => 'cover sfondo',
                'img' => array(
                    'class' => 'cover-image',
                    'src' => 'assets/images/collection-img.jpg'
                )
            ),
            'div' => array(
                'class' => 'cover-mob sfondo-mob',
                'img' => array(
                    'class' => 'cover-image-mob',
                    'src' => 'assets/images/collection-img-mobile.jpg'
                )
            ),
            'a' => array(
                'class' => 'button order light',
                'div' => array(
                    'class' => 'data-min',
                    'div' => array(
                        'class' => 'label-holder',
                        'img' => array(
                            'src' => 'assets/images/sfondo-cta.jpg'
                        ),
                        'p' => array(
                            'class' => 'label',
                            'strong' => 'text'
                        )
                    ),
                    'div_1' => array(
                        'class' => 'price-holder',
                    )
                )
            ),
            'p' => array(
                'class' => 'text-numero-1',
                'span' => array(
                    'strong' => '',
                    'strong_1' => 'text',
                    'strong_2' => 'text',
                    'strong_3' => array(
                        'class' => 'text-anziche',
                        'strike' => 'text'
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    'section_5' => array(
        'class' => 'banner resize',
        'id' => 'num1',
        'contents' => array(
            'div' => array(
                'class' => 'cover'
            ),
            'div_1' => array(
                'class' => 'container',
                'img' => array(
                    'class' => 'banner-image',
                    'src' => 'assets/images/number-1.png'
                ),
                'p' => array(
                    'class' => 'cta num1-cta',
                    'span' => array(
                        'a' => 'text'
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    'section_6' => array(
        'class' => 'gallery',
        'id' => 'gifts',
        'contents' => array(
            'p' => array(
                'class' => 'title gifts-title',
                'span' => array(
                    'strong' => array(
                        'strong' => 'text'
                    )
                )
            ),
            'div' => array(
                'class' => 'container',
                'div' => array(
                    'class' => 'arrow-container prev',
                    'img' => array(
                        'class' => 'arrow',
                        'src' => 'assets/images/freccia-sx_1.png'
                    )
                ),
                'div_1' => array(
                    'class' => 'arrow-container next',
                    'img' => array(
                        'class' => 'arrow',
                        'src' => 'assets/images/freccia-dx_1.png'
                    )
                ),
                'div_2' => array(
                    'class' => 'gallery-holder',
                    'div' => array(
                        'class' => 'internal double',
                        'div' => array(
                            'class' => 'gallery-item',
                            'div' => array(
                                'class' => 'wrapper gifts-wrapper',
                                'img' => array(
                                    'class' => 'thumb',
                                    'src' => 'assets/images/gift-1.jpg'
                                ),
                                'p' => array(
                                    'class' => 'caption gifts-caption',
                                    'span' => 'text'
                                )
                            )
                        ),
                        'div_1' => array(
                            'class' => 'gallery-item',
                            'div' => array(
                                'class' => 'wrapper gifts-wrapper',
                                'img' => array(
                                    'class' => 'thumb',
                                    'src' => 'assets/images/gift-2.jpg'
                                ),
                                'p' => array(
                                    'class' => 'caption gifts-caption',
                                    'span' => 'text'
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            ),
            'div_1' => array(
                'class' => 'counter'
            ),
            'p' => array(
                'class' => 'disclaimer gifts-disclaimer',
                'span' => array(
                    'span' => 'text'
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    'section_7' => array(
        'class' => 'footer',
        'contents' => array(
            'div' => array(
                'class' => 'container',
                'div' => array(
                    'class' => 'box',
                    'div' => array(
                        'class' => 'wrapper',
                        'p' => array(
                            'class' => 'icon pointer',
                            'img' => array(
                                'src' => 'assets/images/icn-piano-opera.png'
                            )
                        ),
                        'a' => array(
                            'class' => 'link',
                            'p' => array(
                                'class' => 'title',
                                'span' => 'text'
                            )
                        )
                    )
                ),
                'div_1' => array(
                    'class' => 'box',
                    'div' => array(
                        'class' => 'wrapper',
                        'p' => array(
                            'class' => 'icon pointer',
                            'img' => array(
                                'src' => 'assets/images/icn-piano-opera.png'
                            )
                        ),
                        'a' => array(
                            'class' => 'link gtm-externallinks',
                            'p' => array(
                                'class' => 'title',
                                'span' => 'text'
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    'section_8' => array(
        'class' => 'partners resize',
        'contents' => array(
            'div' => array(
                'class' => 'container',
                'img' => array(
                    'class' => 'partner',
                    'src' => 'assets/images/logo-dinsey-lucasfilm_2_1.png'
                ),
                'img_1' => array(
                    'class' => 'partner',
                    'src' => 'assets/images/logo-mondadori_1_1.png'
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    'section9' => array(
        'class' => 'partners-light',
        'contents' => array(
            'div' => array(
                'class' => 'container',
                'img' => array(
                    'class' => 'partner',
                    'src' => 'assets/images/copyrightLucasLight.png'
                )
            )
        )
    ));
 foreach ($MiniSiteStructureArray as $section => $sectionStructure) {
    foreach ($sectionStructure['contents'] as $tag => $contents) {
        $tags[] = $tag;
    }
    $a = formatTag($tags);
    $sections[] = $section;
}
$b = formatTag($sections);
```

as you can see html tags aren't well formed (es. div and div_1), so I have created this function

```
function formatTag($tags) {
$correctTags = array();
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    switch ($tag) {
        case strpos($tag, "img"):
            $tag = "img";
            break;
        case strpos($tag, "div"):
            $tag = "div";
            break;
        case strpos($tag, "a"):
            $tag = "a";
            break;
        case strpos($tag, "p"):
            $tag = "p";
            break;
        case strpos($tag, "section"):
            $tag = "section";
            break;
    }
    array_push($correctTags, $tag);
}
return $correctTags;
}
```

So my idea is to recreate the array with new keys (well formed tag).
But now i'm stuck.
Supposing that the `newKeysArray` is done and supposing to create `section_1`.
How can I do?

Thanks

Edit : New array

```
    $structureArray = array(
    'tag' => 'section_8',
    'class' => 'partners resize',
    'contents' => array(
        'tag' => 'div',
        'class' => 'container',
        'contents' => array(
            'tag' => 'img',
            'class' => 'partner',
            'src' => 'assets/images/logo-dinsey-lucasfilm_2_1.png'
        )
    )
);
```

Better?

Edit_2 : NewNewArray

```
  $structureArray = array(
    'tag' => array(
        'tagName' => 'section_1',
        'class' => 'main full',
        'contents' => array(
            'tag' => array(
                'tagName' => 'img',
                'class' => 'logo',
                'src' => 'assets/images/logo-480x176.png'
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'tag_1' => array(
        'tagName' => 'div',
        'class' => 'cover sfondo',
        'contents' => array(
            'tag' => array(
                'tagName' => 'img',
                'class' => 'cover-image',
                'src' => 'assets/images/cover-img-header.png'
            )
        ),
    ),
);
```

This should be better, don't you think?
In this case I manually incremented key tag because in html page it not appears

Edit_3_I_hope: NewNewNewArray

```
 $structureArray = array(
    'tag' => array(
        'tagName' => 'section_1',
        'tagAttributes' => array(
            'class' => 'main full',
        ),
        'contents' => array(
            'tag' => array(
                'tagName' => 'img',
                'tagAttributes' => array(
                    'class' => 'logo',
                    'src' => 'assets/images/logo-480x176.png'
                )
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'tag_1' => array(
        'tagName' => 'div',
        'tagAttributes' => array(
            'class' => 'cover sfondo',
        ),
        'contents' => array(
            'tag' => array(
                'tagName' => 'img',
                'tagAttributes' => array(
                    'class' => 'cover-image',
                    'src' => 'assets/images/cover-img-header.png'
                )
            )
        ),
    ),
);
```

Now, it seems very good

Comment: How did you get the array? It is clearly flawed. It would be nice if there was an indication whether something is a tag or an attribute. You don't have control over the code that generates the array?

Comment: i have created the array based on a html page.
How can I improve the quality of the array? For example 'tag' => 'img'? 
In this way the key tag helps me to retrieve the data?

Comment: Ah, good, yes it is much better to improve the array generator, so it is easier to turn it back into html. Yes, your new array is a slight improvement, but now you will have problems with the huge amount of attributes that exist: 'class' is certainly not the only one. But why turn html into an array and then back into html? You do realize there are already html parsers for php?

Comment: Yes, i know. 
Obviously array keys must be different, I'm working on it.

"But why turn html into an array and then back into html?"
1) I'm trying to manipulate multidimensional array, exercise.
2) yes, this is the beginning to a final parser.

Bad idea, you think?

Comment: No, not a bad idea. Especially not if it is an exercise. Try to be a bit more systematic: 1. HTML exists out of tags. 2. Tags have a name, attributes and content. 3. Attributes have an name and a value. I'll show an other array in answer... let me write it.

Comment: Yes, atributes can, of course, be simpler than I proposed. It looks perfect to me. :-)

Comment: Great, thank you so much for helping me.
Now I'm working to improve the quality of array.
Later i'll try to create the html page cycling the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My proposal for the array structure:

```
$htmlArray = ['tag'   => ['name' => 'ul'],
              'attrs' => [['name' => 'class','value' => 'beautiful_list'],
                          ['name' => 'id',   'value' => 'unique_list']],
              'text'  => ['tag'  => ['name' => 'li'
                                     'text' => 'item 1'],
                          'tag'  => ['name' => 'li'
                                     'text' => 'item 2']]];
```

I hope this is somewhat clear?

These two is equivalent:

```
array()
[]
```